# How to view Jasper Report Records in the application before Downloading in Java SpringBoot (View and Then Download)

Tags: jasper-reports

We are developing report module in jasper soft. before downloading the report (PDF, EXCEL, CSV, DOC), Need to view the report data in Application first and then download the report

I have developed jasper report downloaded. but am trying to view that report before downloading the report